# Convergence of distance in Hilbert spaces

Tags: convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $C$ be a closed subset of $X$ and {x_n} be a bounded sequence in X. Let $d(\cdot,C)$ be the distance function to $C$. Assume that $d(x_n,C) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Can we claim that $x_n$ converges to some point in $C$?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you only get weak convergence of a subsequence towards a point in $C$.

Think about the case $C = X$ or $C$ being a closed subspace for simple examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what happen if we assume that $x_n\not\in C$ for all $n$? Do we have only weak convergence of a subsequence?

Comment: Does not help. Therefore, I added the second example. If $C$ is a closed subspace you can take any sequence in $C^\perp$ (orthogonal complement) which converges weakly towards $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\vert C \vert \geq 2$ is the interesting case. Let $x,y \in C$ and $x\neq y$. Now construct
$$x_n=\begin{cases}
x, \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\
y, \quad \text{else}
\end{cases}.$$
Because $x,y \in C$ we have $d(x_n, C) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. It is obvious that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ doesn't converges. Like gerw noted you can observe a convergent subsequence.

Since Hilbert spaces are reflexive you can deduce, that bounded sequences have a weak convergent subsequence.